# jQuery datepicker - for loop issue in 'beforeShowDay'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using [jQuery UI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to make a calendar that displays events in a tooltip from a db that are pulled in via ajax and PHP. The problem I'm running into is, only the first event in the array is displaying on its date, rather than everything the ajax returns.

I checked the array contents and length via console.log() and verified it's returning the right information, but apart from that, I'm not sure what else to try.

**Relevant portion of the jQuery:**

```
function calendarModify() {
var cal = $(".caledit");
$.ajax({
    url: "calprocess.php?action=showdates",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (events) {
        cal.datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            beforeShowDay: function (dates) {
                var d = ('0' + dates.getDate()).slice(-2),
                    m = ('0' + (dates.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                    y = dates.getFullYear(),
                    date = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    if (events[i].event_date === date) {
                        return [true, "event", events[i].event_desc];
                    }
                    else {
                        return [true, ""];
                    }
                }
            }
```

(there's more, but it's all working properly)

Comment: You always `return` during the loop, so it will always run only once. What are you trying to do with the values you're returning? `return` halts the function's execution

Comment: Hey nbrooks. This whole function is a result of me trying to piece a bunch of tutorials and other _stackflow_ suggestions to other people's issues together, for starters.

The main goal is to take each JSON object returned from the PHP by ajax, and show its event_desc value in a tooltip over the associated date, which is formatted yyyy-mm-dd in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
I finally got it working! Big thanks to [Andrew Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497356/andrew-whitaker) for providing the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167732/excluding-dates-in-the-jquery-datepicker-using-beforeshowday-and-an-array-of-obj?rq=1) that put me on the right track. My final code (although I'll probably still optimize it a bit) is below:

```
function calendarModify() {
  var cal = $(".caledit");
  $.ajax({
    url: "calprocess.php?action=showdates",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      cal.addClass("loading");
    },
    success: function (events) {
      cal.removeClass("loading");
      cal.datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: function (dates) {
          var d = ('0' + dates.getDate()).slice(-2),
            m = ('0' + (dates.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            y = dates.getFullYear(),
            date = y + "-" + m + "-" + d,
            length = events.length,
            i = 0,
            event = null,
            eventDate = false;
          while (i < length && !eventDate) {
            event = events[i];
            eventDate = event.event_date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
            i++;
            console.log(event);
          }
          if (eventDate) {
            return [true,"event", event.event_desc];
          } else {
            return [true, ""];
          }
        }
        // and more...
```