# Beforeshowday - Jquery - Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I manage to block a list of dates in the jquery datepicker.

After having displayed the datepicker, I'd like to use the "beforeShowDay function" to check if a list of dates is available or not.

For each date of the list, I'd like to alert("available") or ("not available").
Someone told me that I need to "Declare it as a standalone function and re-use it in this case." but I don't know how.

Can you help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

By declaring a standalone function, you should only need to declare a function
Ex.:

```
var validateDay = function(){
//somecode
}
```

But you can find a post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167732/excluding-dates-in-the-jquery-datepicker-using-beforeshowday-and-an-array-of-obj) that has a implementation similar to what you want to do.